# Python/BeautifulSoup only returning first table item

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the data from a website but the below code will only pull the first row from the website's table despite being in a for loop. What am I missing?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas
import xlsxwriter 

r = requests.get("https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/stats/qb.php")
c = r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
all=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"mobile-table double-header"})

l=[]
for item in all:
    d={}
    d["Player"] = (item.find("a",{"class","player-name"}).text.strip())
    l.append(d)

df=pandas.DataFrame(l)
df.to_csv("Output.csv")
```

Comment: It should find all of the "mobile-table" divs, but only the first of the "player-name" divs, since you used `find` instead of `find_all`.  Is that what you wanted?  The first player in each double-header div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used **find** to get the first table occurrence and then iterated over all div.player-name elements using **find_all**.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas

r = requests.get("https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/stats/qb.php")
c = r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
table=soup.find("div",{"class":"mobile-table double-header"})

l = []
for item in table.find_all("a",{"class","player-name"}):
    d={}
    d["Player"] = item.text.strip()
    l.append(d)

df=pandas.DataFrame(l)
df.to_csv("Output.csv")
```

Comment: Ahh. That did it! Such an easy fix. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to know it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can also do something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/stats/qb.php'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
table = soup.select('table#data')
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
print(df)
```

This returns that table in full:

```
    Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  PASSING RUSHING MISC
Rank    Player  CMP ATT PCT YDS Y/A TD  INT SACKS   ATT YDS TD  FL  G   FPTS    FPTS/G  ROST
0   1   Josh Allen (BUF)    409 646 63.3    4407    6.8 36  15  26  122 763 6   3   17  417.7   24.6    99.9%
1   2   Justin Herbert (LAC)    443 672 65.9    5014    7.5 38  15  31  63  302 3   1   17  395.6   23.3    99.8%
2   3   Tom Brady (TB)  485 719 67.5    5316    7.4 43  12  22  28  81  2   3   17  386.7   22.7    96.1%
3   4   Patrick Mahomes II (KC) 436 658 66.3    4828    7.3 37  13  28  66  381 2   4   17  374.2   22.0    99.9%
4   5   Matthew Stafford (LAR)  404 601 67.2    4886    8.1 41  17  30  32  43  0   2   17  346.8   20.4    90.4%
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Let pandas do the work.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/stats/qb.php'
df = pd.read_html(url, header=1)[0]


df[['Player','Team']] = df['Player'].str.extract('(.*)\((.*)\)', expand=True)
df['Player'] = df['Player'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
|   Rank | Player             |   CMP |   ATT |   PCT |   YDS |   Y/A |   TD |   INT |   SACKS |   ATT.1 |   YDS.1 |   TD.1 |   FL |   G |   FPTS |   FPTS/G | ROST   | Team   |
|-------:|:-------------------|------:|------:|------:|------:|------:|-----:|------:|--------:|--------:|--------:|-------:|-----:|----:|-------:|---------:|:-------|:-------|
|      1 | Josh Allen         |   409 |   646 |  63.3 |  4407 |   6.8 |   36 |    15 |      26 |     122 |     763 |      6 |    3 |  17 |  417.7 |     24.6 | 99.9%  | BUF    |
|      2 | Justin Herbert     |   443 |   672 |  65.9 |  5014 |   7.5 |   38 |    15 |      31 |      63 |     302 |      3 |    1 |  17 |  395.6 |     23.3 | 99.8%  | LAC    |
|      3 | Tom Brady          |   485 |   719 |  67.5 |  5316 |   7.4 |   43 |    12 |      22 |      28 |      81 |      2 |    3 |  17 |  386.7 |     22.7 | 96.1%  | TB     |
|      4 | Patrick Mahomes II |   436 |   658 |  66.3 |  4828 |   7.3 |   37 |    13 |      28 |      66 |     381 |      2 |    4 |  17 |  374.2 |     22   | 99.9%  | KC     |
|      5 | Matthew Stafford   |   404 |   601 |  67.2 |  4886 |   8.1 |   41 |    17 |      30 |      32 |      43 |      0 |    2 |  17 |  346.8 |     20.4 | 90.4%  | LAR    |
|      6 | Aaron Rodgers      |   366 |   531 |  68.9 |  4115 |   7.7 |   37 |     4 |      30 |      33 |     101 |      3 |    0 |  16 |  336.3 |     21   | 93.8%  | GB     |
|      7 | Dak Prescott       |   410 |   596 |  68.8 |  4449 |   7.5 |   37 |    10 |      30 |      48 |     146 |      1 |    6 |  16 |  330.4 |     20.7 | 93.9%  | DAL    |
|      8 | Joe Burrow         |   366 |   520 |  70.4 |  4611 |   8.9 |   34 |    14 |      51 |      40 |     118 |      2 |    2 |  16 |  328.1 |     20.5 | 95.7%  | CIN    |
|      9 | Jalen Hurts        |   265 |   432 |  61.3 |  3144 |   7.3 |   16 |     9 |      26 |     139 |     784 |     10 |    2 |  15 |  321.2 |     21.4 | 96.5%  | PHI    |
|     10 | Kyler Murray       |   333 |   481 |  69.2 |  3787 |   7.9 |   24 |    10 |      31 |      88 |     423 |      5 |    0 |  14 |  310.5 |     22.2 | 97.3%  | ARI    |
|     11 | Kirk Cousins       |   372 |   561 |  66.3 |  4221 |   7.5 |   33 |     7 |      28 |      29 |     115 |      1 |    2 |  16 |  307.3 |     19.2 | 76.1%  | MIN    |
|     12 | Ryan Tannehill     |   357 |   531 |  67.2 |  3734 |   7   |   21 |    14 |      47 |      55 |     270 |      7 |    4 |  17 |  282.3 |     16.6 | 17.1%  | TEN    |
|     13 | Derek Carr         |   428 |   626 |  68.4 |  4804 |   7.7 |   23 |    14 |      40 |      40 |     108 |      0 |    5 |  17 |  270.6 |     15.9 | 85.7%  | LV     |
|     14 | Carson Wentz       |   322 |   516 |  62.4 |  3563 |   6.9 |   27 |     7 |      32 |      57 |     215 |      1 |    5 |  17 |  264.9 |     15.6 | 12.4%  | WAS    |
|     15 | Lamar Jackson      |   246 |   382 |  64.4 |  2882 |   7.5 |   16 |    13 |      38 |     134 |     767 |      2 |    3 |  12 |  253   |     21.1 | 99.5%  | BAL    |
|     16 | Russell Wilson     |   259 |   400 |  64.8 |  3113 |   7.8 |   25 |     6 |      33 |      43 |     183 |      2 |    1 |  14 |  248.7 |     17.8 | 93.1%  | DEN    |
|     17 | Jimmy Garoppolo    |   301 |   441 |  68.3 |  3810 |   8.6 |   20 |    12 |      29 |      38 |      51 |      3 |    3 |  15 |  239.5 |     16   | 3.1%   | SF     |
|     18 | Mac Jones          |   352 |   521 |  67.6 |  3801 |   7.3 |   22 |    13 |      28 |      44 |     129 |      0 |    3 |  17 |  238   |     14   | 28.3%  | NE     |
|     19 | Taylor Heinicke    |   321 |   494 |  65   |  3419 |   6.9 |   20 |    15 |      38 |      60 |     313 |      1 |    2 |  16 |  236.7 |     14.8 | 0.6%   | WAS    |
|     20 | Matt Ryan          |   375 |   560 |  67   |  3968 |   7.1 |   20 |    12 |      40 |      40 |      82 |      1 |    4 |  17 |  234.8 |     13.8 | 34.1%  | IND    |
|     21 | Ben Roethlisberger |   390 |   605 |  64.5 |  3740 |   6.2 |   22 |    10 |      38 |      20 |       5 |      1 |    5 |  16 |  228   |     14.3 | 13.6%  | FA     |
|     22 | Trevor Lawrence    |   359 |   602 |  59.6 |  3641 |   6   |   12 |    17 |      32 |      73 |     334 |      2 |    5 |  17 |  216   |     12.7 | 49.0%  | JAC    |
|     23 | Teddy Bridgewater  |   285 |   426 |  66.9 |  3052 |   7.2 |   18 |     7 |      31 |      30 |     106 |      2 |    1 |  14 |  209.8 |     15   | 0.8%   | MIA    |
|     24 | Jared Goff         |   332 |   494 |  67.2 |  3245 |   6.6 |   19 |     8 |      35 |      17 |      87 |      0 |    6 |  14 |  202.4 |     14.5 | 13.2%  | DET    |
|     25 | Baker Mayfield     |   253 |   418 |  60.5 |  3010 |   7.2 |   17 |    13 |      43 |      37 |     134 |      1 |    3 |  14 |  193.8 |     13.8 | 8.3%   | CAR    |
|     26 | Tua Tagovailoa     |   263 |   388 |  67.8 |  2653 |   6.8 |   16 |    10 |      20 |      42 |     128 |      3 |    1 |  13 |  190.9 |     14.7 | 61.9%  | MIA    |
|     27 | Daniel Jones       |   232 |   361 |  64.3 |  2428 |   6.7 |   10 |     7 |      22 |      62 |     298 |      2 |    3 |  11 |  173.6 |     15.8 | 17.5%  | NYG    |
|     28 | Sam Darnold        |   243 |   406 |  59.9 |  2527 |   6.2 |    9 |    13 |      35 |      48 |     222 |      5 |    4 |  12 |  170.5 |     14.2 | 1.8%   | CAR    |
|     29 | Davis Mills        |   263 |   394 |  66.8 |  2664 |   6.8 |   16 |    10 |      31 |      18 |      44 |      0 |    1 |  13 |  167   |     12.8 | 5.0%   | HOU    |
|     30 | Zach Wilson        |   213 |   383 |  55.6 |  2334 |   6.1 |    9 |    11 |      44 |      29 |     185 |      4 |    1 |  13 |  162.9 |     12.5 | 12.2%  | NYJ    |
|     31 | Justin Fields      |   159 |   270 |  58.9 |  1870 |   6.9 |    7 |    10 |      36 |      72 |     420 |      2 |    5 |  12 |  136.9 |     11.4 | 44.2%  | CHI    |
|     32 | Taysom Hill        |    78 |   134 |  58.2 |   978 |   7.3 |    4 |     5 |       9 |      70 |     374 |      5 |    0 |  12 |  122.8 |     10.2 | 3.7%   | NO     |
|     33 | Jameis Winston     |    95 |   161 |  59   |  1170 |   7.3 |   14 |     3 |      11 |      32 |     166 |      1 |    1 |   7 |  120.3 |     17.2 | 29.4%  | NO     |
|     34 | Trevor Siemian     |   108 |   188 |  57.4 |  1154 |   6.1 |   11 |     3 |       9 |       9 |      20 |      1 |    1 |   6 |   93.2 |     15.5 | 0.1%   | CHI    |
|     35 | Andy Dalton        |   149 |   236 |  63.1 |  1515 |   6.4 |    8 |     9 |      18 |      16 |      76 |      0 |    1 |   8 |   93.1 |     11.6 | 0.6%   | NO     |
|     36 | Cam Newton         |    69 |   126 |  54.8 |   684 |   5.4 |    4 |     5 |      10 |      47 |     230 |      5 |    1 |   8 |   91.3 |     11.4 | 9.1%   | FA     |
|     37 | Tyrod Taylor       |    91 |   150 |  60.7 |   966 |   6.4 |    5 |     5 |      13 |      19 |     151 |      3 |    0 |   6 |   86.7 |     14.5 | 0.6%   | NYG    |
|     38 | Tyler Huntley      |   122 |   188 |  64.9 |  1081 |   5.8 |    3 |     4 |      18 |      47 |     294 |      2 |    3 |   7 |   86.7 |     12.4 | 0.7%   | BAL    |
|     39 | Jacoby Brissett    |   141 |   225 |  62.7 |  1283 |   5.7 |    5 |     4 |      19 |      19 |      70 |      1 |    3 |  11 |   76.4 |      6.9 | 2.0%   | CLE    |
|     40 | Trey Lance         |    41 |    71 |  57.7 |   603 |   8.5 |    5 |     2 |       4 |      38 |     168 |      1 |    0 |   6 |   67   |     11.2 | 87.4%  | SF     |
|     41 | Geno Smith         |    65 |    95 |  68.4 |   702 |   7.4 |    5 |     1 |      13 |       9 |      42 |      1 |    1 |   4 |   55.3 |     13.8 | 1.7%   | SEA    |
|     42 | Drew Lock          |    67 |   111 |  60.4 |   787 |   7.1 |    2 |     2 |       9 |      10 |      53 |      2 |    1 |   6 |   52.8 |      8.8 | 2.3%   | SEA    |
|     43 | Mike White         |    88 |   132 |  66.7 |   953 |   7.2 |    5 |     8 |       4 |       5 |      -1 |      0 |    0 |   4 |   52   |     13   | 0.6%   | NYJ    |
|     44 | Josh Johnson       |    57 |    85 |  67.1 |   638 |   7.5 |    5 |     2 |       3 |       9 |      28 |      0 |    0 |   4 |   48.4 |     12.1 | 0.1%   | DEN    |
|     45 | Colt McCoy         |    74 |    99 |  74.7 |   740 |   7.5 |    3 |     1 |       6 |      22 |      37 |      0 |    1 |   8 |   42.3 |      5.3 | 0.1%   | ARI    |
|     46 | Mike Glennon       |    90 |   167 |  53.9 |   790 |   4.7 |    4 |    10 |       9 |       7 |      33 |      1 |    3 |   6 |   40.9 |      6.8 | 0.6%   | FA     |
|     47 | Gardner Minshew II |    41 |    60 |  68.3 |   439 |   7.3 |    4 |     1 |       5 |       9 |      21 |      0 |    0 |   3 |   34.6 |     11.5 | 0.7%   | PHI    |
|     48 | Tim Boyle          |    61 |    94 |  64.9 |   526 |   5.6 |    3 |     6 |       0 |       2 |      13 |      0 |    0 |   4 |   30.4 |      7.6 | 0.1%   | DET    |
|     49 | Case Keenum        |    47 |    72 |  65.3 |   462 |   6.4 |    3 |     1 |       5 |      12 |      22 |      0 |    1 |   5 |   29.6 |      5.9 | 0.1%   | BUF    |
|     50 | Cooper Rush        |    30 |    47 |  63.8 |   422 |   9   |    3 |     1 |       3 |       9 |      -8 |      0 |    1 |   4 |   25.1 |      6.3 | 0.1%   | DAL    |
|     51 | Jordan Love        |    36 |    62 |  58.1 |   411 |   6.6 |    2 |     3 |       3 |      12 |      27 |      0 |    1 |   6 |   24.2 |      4   | 0.8%   | GB     |
|     52 | Joe Flacco         |    27 |    42 |  64.3 |   338 |   8   |    3 |     0 |       2 |       2 |       3 |      0 |    1 |   2 |   23.8 |     11.9 | 0.7%   | NYJ    |
|     53 | Mason Rudolph      |    35 |    58 |  60.3 |   277 |   4.8 |    1 |     1 |       0 |       5 |      53 |      0 |    0 |   2 |   19.4 |      9.7 | 0.6%   | PIT    |
|     54 | PJ Walker          |    36 |    66 |  54.5 |   362 |   5.5 |    1 |     3 |       7 |       7 |      13 |      0 |    1 |   5 |   16.8 |      3.4 | 0.0%   | CAR    |
|     55 | Nick Foles         |    24 |    35 |  68.6 |   250 |   7.1 |    1 |     0 |       4 |       4 |       8 |      0 |    0 |   1 |   16.8 |     16.8 | 0.1%   | IND    |
|     56 | Marcus Mariota     |     1 |     2 |  50   |     4 |   2   |    0 |     0 |       0 |      13 |      87 |      1 |    0 |   7 |   14.9 |      2.1 | 5.8%   | ATL    |
|     57 | Jake Fromm         |    27 |    60 |  45   |   210 |   3.5 |    1 |     3 |       6 |       8 |      65 |      0 |    1 |   3 |   13.9 |      4.6 | 1.0%   | FA     |
|     58 | Brandon Allen      |    17 |    34 |  50   |   149 |   4.4 |    2 |     0 |       4 |       7 |      -1 |      0 |    0 |   5 |   13.8 |      2.8 | 0.1%   | CIN    |
|     59 | Sean Mannion       |    22 |    36 |  61.1 |   189 |   5.3 |    1 |     0 |       2 |       2 |      14 |      0 |    0 |   1 |   13   |     13   | 0.1%   | MIN    |
|     60 | Brian Hoyer        |     9 |    11 |  81.8 |   227 |  20.6 |    1 |     0 |       0 |      11 |      -8 |      0 |    0 |   5 |   12.3 |      2.5 | 0.0%   | NE     |
|     61 | Nick Mullens       |    20 |    30 |  66.7 |   147 |   4.9 |    1 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   1 |    9.9 |      9.9 | 0.1%   | LV     |
|     62 | Mitch Trubisky     |     6 |     8 |  75   |    43 |   5.4 |    0 |     1 |       0 |      13 |      24 |      1 |    0 |   5 |    9.1 |      1.8 | 4.2%   | PIT    |
|     63 | Kyle Allen         |    12 |    19 |  63.2 |   120 |   6.3 |    1 |     0 |       2 |       2 |      11 |      0 |    1 |   2 |    7.9 |      4   | 0.1%   | HOU    |
|     64 | Garrett Gilbert    |    20 |    31 |  64.5 |   194 |   6.3 |    0 |     0 |       2 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   1 |    7.8 |      7.8 | 0.0%   | FA     |
|     65 | Ian Book           |    12 |    20 |  60   |   135 |   6.8 |    0 |     2 |       8 |       3 |       6 |      0 |    0 |   1 |    4   |      4   | 0.0%   | NO     |
|     66 | Chad Henne         |    11 |    16 |  68.8 |    82 |   5.1 |    0 |     0 |       0 |       8 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   4 |    3.3 |      0.8 | 0.1%   | KC     |
|     67 | Chris Streveler    |     6 |     9 |  66.7 |    36 |   4   |    0 |     0 |       2 |       3 |       6 |      0 |    0 |   2 |    2   |      1   | 0.0%   | NYJ    |
|     68 | Blaine Gabbert     |     7 |    11 |  63.6 |    67 |   6.1 |    0 |     0 |       1 |       9 |      -7 |      0 |    0 |   6 |    1.9 |      0.3 | 0.1%   | TB     |
|     69 | C.J. Beathard      |     2 |     2 | 100   |    33 |  16.5 |    0 |     0 |       0 |       1 |       2 |      0 |    0 |   2 |    1.5 |      0.8 | 0.0%   | JAC    |
|     70 | Sam Ehlinger       |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       3 |       9 |      0 |    0 |   3 |    0.9 |      0.3 | 0.1%   | IND    |
|     71 | Ryan Fitzpatrick   |     3 |     6 |  50   |    13 |   2.2 |    0 |     0 |       1 |       1 |       2 |      0 |    0 |   1 |    0.7 |      0.7 | 0.1%   | FA     |
|     72 | David Blough       |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       1 |       1 |       6 |      0 |    0 |   1 |    0.6 |      0.6 | 0.0%   | DET    |
|     73 | Nathan Peterman    |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       2 |       2 |      0 |    0 |   1 |    0.2 |      0.2 | 0.1%   | CHI    |
|     74 | Kellen Mond        |     2 |     3 |  66.7 |     5 |   1.7 |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   2 |    0.2 |      0.1 | 0.2%   | MIN    |
|     75 | Stone Smartt       |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | LAC    |
|     76 | Jared Bernhardt    |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | ATL    |
|     77 | Chris Oladokun     |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | PIT    |
|     78 | Bryce Perkins      |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | LAR    |
|     79 | Shane Buechele     |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | KC     |
|     80 | Jacob Eason        |     2 |     5 |  40   |    25 |   5   |    0 |     1 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   1 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | SEA    |
|     81 | Jarrett Stidham    |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.1%   | LV     |
|     82 | John Lovett        |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | MIA    |
|     83 | Desmond Ridder     |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 2.1%   | ATL    |
|     84 | Reid Sinnett       |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | PHI    |
|     85 | Jack Coan          |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | IND    |
|     86 | Ben DiNucci        |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.1%   | DAL    |
|     87 | Jarrett Guarantano |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | ARI    |
|     88 | Kyle Trask         |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.2%   | TB     |
|     89 | K.J. Costello      |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | NO     |
|     90 | Brock Purdy        |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.1%   | SF     |
|     91 | Carson Strong      |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.1%   | PHI    |
|     92 | Sam Howell         |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.7%   | WAS    |
|     93 | E.J. Perry         |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | JAC    |
|     94 | Skylar Thompson    |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | MIA    |
|     95 | Drew Plitt         |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | CIN    |
|     96 | Armani Rogers      |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | WAS    |
|     97 | Malik Willis       |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 1.7%   | TEN    |
|     98 | Bailey Zappe       |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.1%   | NE     |
|     99 | Dustin Crum        |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | KC     |
|    100 | Anthony Brown      |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | BAL    |
|    101 | Matt Corral        |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.8%   | CAR    |
|    102 | Jake Browning      |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | CIN    |
|    103 | Kenny Pickett      |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 5.2%   | PIT    |
|    104 | Chase Garbers      |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | LV     |
|    105 | Erik Ainge         |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | NYJ    |
|    106 | Hunter Cantwell    |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | BAL    |
|    107 | Ben Chappell       |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | WAS    |
|    108 | Adam Froman        |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | ATL    |
|    109 | Trace McSorley     |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   1 |    0   |      0   | 0.3%   | ARI    |
|    110 | Keith Null         |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | CAR    |
|    111 | Brett Ratliff      |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | TEN    |
|    112 | Brian Brohm        |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | BUF    |
|    113 | Joshua Dobbs       |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.1%   | CLE    |
|    114 | Deshaun Watson     |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 39.0%  | CLE    |
|    115 | Nate Sudfeld       |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | SF     |
|    116 | Will Grier         |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | DAL    |
|    117 | Brett Rypien       |     0 |     2 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   1 |    0   |      0   | 0.1%   | DEN    |
|    118 | Easton Stick       |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | LAC    |
|    119 | Danny Etling       |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | GB     |
|    120 | Matt Barkley       |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | BUF    |
|    121 | Ryan Griffin       |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | TB     |
|    122 | Brett Smith        |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | TB     |
|    123 | Jeff Driskel       |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   0 |    0   |      0   | 0.0%   | HOU    |
|    124 | Kurt Benkert       |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       2 |      -1 |      0 |    0 |   1 |   -0.1 |     -0.1 | 0.0%   | FA     |
|    125 | Chase Daniel       |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       2 |      -2 |      0 |    0 |   1 |   -0.2 |     -0.2 | 0.1%   | LAC    |
|    126 | Davis Webb         |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       2 |      -3 |      0 |    0 |   1 |   -0.3 |     -0.3 | 0.0%   | NYG    |
|    127 | Feleipe Franks     |     0 |     1 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     1 |       0 |       3 |       6 |      0 |    0 |   6 |   -0.4 |     -0.1 | 0.1%   | ATL    |
|    128 | Logan Woodside     |     0 |     0 |   0   |     0 |   0   |    0 |     0 |       0 |       6 |      -6 |      0 |    0 |   4 |   -0.6 |     -0.2 | 0.0%   | TEN    |
|    129 | John Wolford       |     1 |     4 |  25   |     5 |   1.3 |    0 |     1 |       1 |       2 |      -1 |      0 |    0 |   2 |   -0.9 |     -0.5 | 0.1%   | LAR    |
|    130 | Josh Rosen         |     2 |    11 |  18.2 |    19 |   1.7 |    0 |     2 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      0 |    0 |   3 |   -1.2 |     -0.4 | 0.0%   | CLE    |
```